# PHP strlen question

Tags: php, validation, strlen

Ok I am checking that a string is at least 4 characters long and 25 or less characters short

I tried to use strlen like this

```
$userNameSignupLength = strlen($userNameSignup);

else if($userNameSignupLength<4 && $userNameSignupLength>25) {

            $userNameSignupError = "Must be between 4 to 25 characters long";

        }
```

but it doesn't work... what did I do wrong?

Comment: Same as @Kevin. And what you want is `>= 25` not `> 25`.

Comment: You might want to look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php , strlen counts multibyte characters like UTF-8 incorrectly.

Comment: @p4blo, no - 25 is ok, so he wants to check `> 25` for ones which are too long.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `strlen` is correct to check the length of a string (in bytes). But a number cannot be both smaller than 4 *and* greater than 25 at the same time. Use `||` instead:

```
if ($userNameSignupLength < 4 || $userNameSignupLength > 25)
```

Now the condition is fulfilled if the number is either smaller than 4 *or* greater than 25.

Comment: thank you very much lol I do that all the time mess up my ands and ors >< one day I will get it lol ^.^

Answer (score 2):

Change the && to ||

```
else if ($userNameSignupLength<4 || $userNameSignupLength>25)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want an OR there:

```
else if($userNameSignupLength < 4 || $userNameSignupLength > 25) {
```

Like Gumbo said, the length cannot possibly be both less than 4 AND greater than 25.  `&&` means `and`.

Answer (score 2):

and get rid of the 'else' in front of the 'if' keyword!

Answer (score -1):

With your code, it is evident that you are trying to validate a text field. You have not shared html of this code. Anyways , from my expertise i will say that you should not use &&. You should use ||. Also you should not directly use else if. You should use if for this code.