# How to check if post field is from 8 - 20 characters long

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP strlen question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492926/php-strlen-question)

how to check if text from post field is 8 - 20 characters long? Is it done with strlen, and could you give me some example, please?

Comment: really, you can't even be bothered to try and hit `http://php.net/strlen`?

Comment: Or, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492926/php-strlen-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$variable = $_POST['your-field-name']; // or $_GET['']; depends on your post method

if(strlen($variable) > 7 && strlen($variable) < 21) {
 return true;
} else {
 return false;
}
```

Comment: and what will happen if I use if(strlen($variable) > 7 || strlen($variable) < 21) instead of &&?

Comment: any number would work because 0 is smaller than 21 and 30 is larger than 7, || checks for one of the conditions to be true

Answer (score 0):

It's easy:

```
$item = $_POST['item'];
if (strlen($item) >= 8 && strlen($item) <= 20) { /*do something*/ }
```

Good luck!
Konstantin

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// get the length of the text. we take the value by reference
// because there is the risk it doesn't exist (such as when
// no data is submitted).
$textLen = strlen($myTextField = &$_POST['my_text_field']);

// test its length
if ($textLen >= 8 && $textLen <= 20) {
    echo 'Text is the right length.';
} else {
    echo 'Text is the wrong length.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to use [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php):

```
strlen($_POST['shinyHappyString']) > 7 && strlen($_POST['shinyHappyString']) < 21
```

However, if you encounter multi-byte strings, you are in trouble. Therefore I recommend you to use [`grapheme_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.grapheme-strlen.php) or [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) instead. You can check how they use it in [Symfony2's validators](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/MinLengthValidator.php).